# $\sum$ vs $\prod$ and constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just to make sure, are the following correct?

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \alpha x_{i}=\alpha \sum_{i=0}^{n} x_{i}$

$\prod_{i=0}^{n} \alpha x_{i} =\alpha^{n}\prod_{i=0}^{n}x_{i}$

Comment: Except that the second one must have $\alpha^{n+1}$

Comment: Check by expanding with $n=3$.

Comment: @OpenBall because the counter is from $0$ right? if it was from $1$ so it is $\alpha^{n}$?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  First one is fine.  On the second one you have the right idea but it should be $\alpha^{n+1}$ on the RHS, because when $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n$ it ($i$) takes $n+1$ total values.